# Azure aks private cluster - How show list workload

Tags: azure, aks, private

I learning work with aks in azure. I want create private aks. I know manage or deploy to cluster over az aks command invoke....  But I have problem with portal.azure.com. When I click to list Worlkloads I get error:

"Unable to reach the api server 'https://fa925f1ecc55291698ec4fd8a0ecc5fe-priv.portal.hcp.westeurope.azmk8s.io' or api server is too busy to respond. Check your network settings and refresh to try again."

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gk04O.png)

What need I doing when I see list workloads?

Thank you for answer

Answer (score 0):

You will not be able to use the portal UI to show workloads on a private cluster, the portal does not have access to the API server to be able to query for those items.

To list workloads you would either using command invoke to run kubectl commands, or setup a jump box on the same vNet (or a connected vNet) to run kubectl from.